# html page render over bootstrap modal using ajax issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have render html page over bootstrap modal using ajax, page has rendered without any issue but i want to show html page in bootstrap modal not over bootstrap modal.

If i hide html page using style css `display:block`,it will show bootstrap modal. it means my html page is not rendering in bootstrap modal it renders over bootstrap modal.

What i have done :

Jquery Code :

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#builder_modal').click(function(event) {
        console.log("Builder");
        $.ajax({
            url: '_Add_new_commision_package',
            type: 'post'
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            jQuery('#categoryModal .modal-content').html(data);
            $('#categoryModal').modal({
                "backdrop": "static"
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Bootstrap Modal :

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="categoryModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So what i do so that html page render in bootstrap modal ?

Image :
[image]

Comment: Possibly the `data` returned from the AJAX call is not a partial? What does `data` contain?

Comment: data contain an html page

Comment: Have you tried `$('#categoryModal .modal-content').append(data);`?

Comment: i did but nothing new happend.

Comment: Any errors thrown on the browser? What is this built on, MVC?

Comment: I added an image above, there below is bootstrap modal and above is html page. which should be come into bootstrap modal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116128/discussion-between-blue-eyed-behemoth-and-manish-tiwari).